# Matlab marker size in increments

Tags: matlab-figure

all,
I would like to increase the marker size in a 3D plot in increments. I have data measured at various time points and would like the markers to get larger with each successive measurement.

I've attached a  [sample data file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1vM0xxNIIRDIrcZfYoO78mWCzBjAThLgY). Data is formatted as 6 variables (a1,a2,a3,b1,b2,b3), each containing 7 measurements of 3 variables. a and b are conditions; 1, 2, and 3 are specimens.

So far, the code for the graph is as follows:

```
%Create two series of matrices containing data for each condition.
ax = [(a1(:,1)),(a2(:,1)),(a3(:,1))]; 
ay = [(a1(:,2)),(a2(:,2)),(a3(:,2))];
az = [(a1(:,3)),(a2(:,3)),(a3(:,3))];

bx = [(b1(:,1)),(b2(:,1)),(b3(:,1))];
by = [(b1(:,2)),(b2(:,2)),(b3(:,2))];
bz = [(b1(:,3)),(b2(:,3)),(b3(:,3))];

%Make line plot of all data
figure_a = plot3(ax,ay,az, 'Color', 'r', 'Marker','o'); hold on;
figure_b = plot3(bx,by,bz,'Color', 'b', 'Marker','s');
```

Comment: This is generally a pretty good first post, one point you could improve on is to include the sample data file in a code block for us. Requiring people to download your file is not time-proof and just makes more steps to help you.

Comment: [`'MarkerSize'`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.line-properties.html#property_d119e565277) would probably be good start.

Comment: Yes, I understand how marker size works, but that typically changes all the markers to a specific size. I need markers along the same plotted line to change.

Comment: So you call `plot` for each measurement.

Comment: That won't work with the current layout of the code. That changes the size for consecutive lines being plotted, not the markers on each line.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Marker size is a homogeneous property of the line object, so you need a plot object per size desired.

Comment: It must be possible. Check out panel 'e' here: https://www.nature.com/articles/nature08961/figures/1

This is the type of figure I'm trying to recreate with the data. The plotted points increase along each individual line, not across lines.

Comment: That's a [`scatter3`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatter3.html) plot with another line plotted behind it.

Comment: Ah! I see! I can just add a line to a scatter plot and achieve the same result. Thanks!